# Initializing Swift properties that require "self" as an argument

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have a Swift class that I'd like to look something like this:

```
class UpdateManager {
  let timer: NSTimer

  init() {
    timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 600, target: self, selector: "check", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

  func check() {
    // Do some stuff
  }
}
```

However, Swift doesn't like the fact that I'm passing `self` to the `NSTimer` initializer. Am I breaking some pattern here? How is one supposed to accomplish initialization like this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've found the primary use case of the [Implicitly Unwrapped Optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID334).

- You need to access `self` from `init`, before `timer` is initialized.
- Otherwise, `timer` should *never* be nil, so you shouldn't have to check it outside of `init`.

So, you should declare `let timer: NSTimer!`.

Comment: This is great. By the time you answered I had figured out how to use Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals with `var` but didn't know that they were compatible with `let`. Thanks!

Comment: It's a good question, and frankly I'm surprised it hasn't been asked already! It's nice to see IUOs used for their true purpose, rather than automatically being sprinkled everywhere when Obj-C APIs are imported...

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that Swift 2 has changed what works. I'm using code like the following:

```
@objc class Test : NSObject {
    var timer : NSTimer!
    init text() {
        super.init()
        timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: "timerFired:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    }
}
```

Needed both @objc declaration and NSObject subclass.
Also timer needs to be a var, not let.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the implicitly unwrapped optional, I found that to get the code working I needed to subclass NSObject and to also add the timer to current run loop.

```
class UpdateManager:NSObject {
    let timer: NSTimer!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 600, target: self, selector: "check", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    }


    func check() {
        // Do some stuff

    }
}
```

**Updated code based on comments - thank you to jtbandes and Caroline**

```
class UpdateManager {
    let timer: NSTimer!

   init() {

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(600,
            target: self,
            selector: "check",
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
    }


   @objc func check() {
        // Do some stuff

    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(_:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)` instead.

Comment: that removes the need to add the timer to the run loop, but if NSObject isn't subclassed the app crashes with the message: "does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead"

Comment: Instead of subclassing NSObject, you can add the `@objc` attribute to the function as in `@objc func check () {`

Comment: Thanks for this @Caroline, that works and I'm seeing it spelt out in documentation now: “This attribute [`@objc`] is also useful when you’re working with Objective-C classes that use selectors to implement the target-action design pattern—for example, NSTimer or UIButton.” As a point of interest, it's also the case that the use of the **dynamic** keyword can stop the app from crashing, although it's the `@objc` we should be using.