# Reference `self` in Swift instance member declaration

Tags: swift

I have a `struct` set up that accepts a reference as a single initialization parameter:

```
internal struct NodeState: Equatable {
    weak var node: Node! = nil
    // ...

    init(node: Node) {
        self.node = node
    }
}
```

I want to instantiate a `NodeState` as a member of the `Node` class, passing `self` in to set that weak reference:

```
public class Node: NSObject {
    internal var state = NodeState(node: self)
    // ...
}
```

…but I am getting this weird compile error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject -> () -> Node' to expected argument type 'Node'

Am I not allowed to reference `self` in a member declaration in Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing Swift properties that require "self" as an argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149248/initializing-swift-properties-that-require-self-as-an-argument)

Comment: Just to note that the weird compile error is due to [the `self` method in NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418954-self). In a non-ObjC class the error will simply be "Use of resolved identifier 'self'".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you can't reference `self` in a member class declaration but you can if you make the property lazy and initialize it with a closure. Changing your `Node` class to something like this should work:

```
public class Node: NSObject {
    internal lazy var staticState: NodeState = { NodeState(node: self) }()
}
```

It works because the lazy property isn't initialized until after `self` is initialized. `self` has to be fully initialized before it can be used.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error. :( It seems something to do with the type inference is broken.

Comment: It is compiling for me without error. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Ah, my bad, was missing the explicit type declaration for `staticState`.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I not allowed to reference self in a member declaration in Swift?

Sort of. You can't reference `self` (e.g. calling methods, passing self as a parameter) until the object is fully initialized.

You could use a lazy var in this case, which would work since it can't be accessed until the object is initialized. Here's an example:

```
public class Node: NSObject {
    internal lazy var staticState: NodeState = {
        return NodeState(node: self)
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference self in a closure?

```
public class Node: NSObject {

    lazy var staticState: () -> (NodeState) = {
        [unowned self] in
        return NodeState(node: self)

    }
}
```

I'm explicitly decorating `self` as `unowned` in the closure to prevent a retain cycle.

Comment: Just noticed what was wrong! Your lazy variable here is defined as closure type, not a `NodeState` instance type (which I'm not sure is what OP wants). Therefore, without `[unowned self]` it will indeed create a retain cycle. If you change the declaration to a `NodeState` instance type with an auto-executing closure (as shown in the accepted answer), `[unowned self]` is not required as Swift is clever enough to avoid a retain cycle in that case.

Comment: Right.  This isn't "wrong", it's just a different implementation (not an auto-executing closure).

Comment: When I said "wrong", I meant what was wrong with my original comment (about `[unowned self]` not being required) – not disputing the correctness of your answer.